# ASLR bits of Entropy of mmap()

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, mmap, aslr

I am studying ASLR randomization of mmap(), on x86 system.
I have read in a lot of places that there are 16bits of randomization on the address loaded with mmap().

But in the source code i have found:

```
static unsigned long mmap_rnd(void)
02  {
03          unsigned long rnd = 0;
04   
05         /*
06          *  8 bits of randomness in 32bit mmaps, 20 address space bits
07          * 28 bits of randomness in 64bit mmaps, 40 address space bits
08          */
09          if (current->flags & PF_RANDOMIZE) {
10                  if (mmap_is_ia32())
11                          rnd = (long)get_random_int() % (1<<8);
12                  else 
13                          rnd = (long)(get_random_int() % (1<<28));
14          }
15          return rnd << PAGE_SHIFT;
16  }
```

So, that would be only 8bits of randomness.

But in fact, running some test, i get the following address (stack-heap-mmap)
bf937000,09a60000,b774b000

bfa86000,090ef000,b76e2000

Its more than 16 bits if it can be b77XX000 and b76XX000!!!!

Any help on this?

Answer (score 2):

`PAGE_SHIFT` is shifting that randomness to a different bit position. The difference between your `mmap` addresses is indeed:

```
 b774b000
-b76e2000
---------
    69000
```

I don't know what the value of `PAGE_SHIFT` is, but if it's 12 for example, then you have `0x69` difference which perfectly fits in 8-bits.

Comment: Ok, in terms of difference its true, but if you have tu guest the addres of mmap zone, you have to work on more than 16bits...

Comment: Can you verify your spelling before posting? I'm having a bit of a hard time understanding you. I'm assuming `guest` is a typo, but are you trying to _guess_ the address of mmap zone? Why would you want to do that? And what is the problem if that address is more than 16-bits? In fact, why would it be 16-bits on a 32-bit machine?

Comment: Yes, i was meaning guess. This is a study of stack overflow exploits, you have to know the address of system() function on libc, so if the address is somethin like:
0xb77XX000 
(XX because of ASLR), its ok, it will take 2^16 attempts on a brute force attack.