# ASLR Entropy Bits for Stack on Linux

Tags: linux, stack, 32-bit, entropy, aslr

I am looking at a [presentation](https://www.usenix.org/sites/default/files/conference/protected-files/cset14_slides_herlands.pdf) from MIT where they explain different types of ASLR implementations.

For example, they point out that for static ASLR, stack has 19-bits of entropy. In my understanding, this means the stack base address can only be randomized to take 2^19 different values.

I want to ask how to calculate that the stack has 19-bits of entropy ?

**Edit:**

After checking online, I found some [explanation](https://xorl.wordpress.com/2011/01/16/linux-kernel-aslr-implementation/) of stack ASLR on Linux. Learning from another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13826479/682869), the code I thought may be relevant is:

```
#ifndef STACK_RND_MASK
#define STACK_RND_MASK (0x7ff >> (PAGE_SHIFT - 12))     /* 8MB of VA */
#endif

static unsigned long randomize_stack_top(unsigned long stack_top)
{
    unsigned int random_variable = 0;

    if ((current->flags & PF_RANDOMIZE) &&
            !(current->personality & ADDR_NO_RANDOMIZE)) {
            random_variable = get_random_int() & STACK_RND_MASK;
            random_variable <<= PAGE_SHIFT;
    }
#ifdef CONFIG_STACK_GROWSUP
    return PAGE_ALIGN(stack_top) + random_variable;
#else
    return PAGE_ALIGN(stack_top) - random_variable;
#endif
}
```

I want to ask if this is the right place to reason about my question ?

Answer (score 7):

Firstly, pages have to be aligned to 4096-byte boundaries, which effectively zeroes the lower 12 bits.

Next, the kernel splits the address space in to `0x00000000 - 0xbfffffff` for user memory and `0xc0000000 - 0xffffffff` for kernel memory. We only care about user memory here, so the kernel memory can be ignored.

If we further split up the user address space into three ranges:

```
       Range        | 2 MSBs 
--------------------+--------
00000000 - 3fffffff |   00
40000000 - 7fffffff |   01
80000000 - bfffffff |   10
```

Generally we don't want the stack in the first range, since that's where the heap lives. This means we only have two possible combinations for the 2 most significant bits, `01` and `10`, effectively turning 2 bits into 1.

We have 32 bits in a 32-bit address, so we can get our 19-bits of stack entropy with:
`32 - (page alignment bits) - (memory partitioning bits) = 32 - 12 - 1 = 19`

Comment: Thanks a lot, but one more question: So that means global variable segment maybe upon the stack or under the stack area?